# Perl split comma separated list with "and"

Tags: regex, perl, csv, split

Using Perl, I would like to `split` a string on the comma and the "and" (that may or may not be preceded by a comma.

1. `"Apple"` gives array `(Apple)`
2. `"Apple and Orange"` gives array `(Apple Orange)`
3. `"Apple, Orange, and Banana"` gives array `(Apple Orange Banana)`

For some reason the following split regex is not working for me:

```
split(/(,| and )/, $string)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
my @list = split /\s*(?:(?:,\s*)?\band\b|,)\s*/, $string;
```

Example:

```
perl -E "say join ':', split /\s*(?:(?:,\s*)?\band\b|,)\s*/, 'apple, orange, and banana'"
apple:orange:banana
```

Or a simpler working case for your example:

```
/,? and |, /
```

Comment: Thanks, works perfect. Could you let me know what `(?:  )` matches?

Comment: It's a non-capturing group. Does what a normal group `()` does, but without capturing the content.

Answer (score 1):

```
my $str = 'Apple, Orange, and Banana';

$str =~ s/,?\s*and\b/,/;
my @words = split /\s*,\s*/, $str;
```

Answer (score 1):

The following [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) should work for you:

```
split /(?: ,?\s*and\s* | ,\s+? )/x;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one solution. It relies on two `split` doing all the heavy lifting, with a `map` for convenience. It's probably not very different from the other answers, but it's clean, and it's fairly easy on the eyes (except maybe for the print). And I think it will work with most variations on whitespace/and/comma.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my @w = ( "Apple", "Apple and Orange", "Apple, Orange, and Banana",
    "Apple, Orange and Banana ,and Pineapple" );

for (@w) {
    print join (':', humanize($_)), "\n";
}


sub humanize {
    my $str = shift;
    my @list = split /\s*and\s*/, $str;
    @list = map { split /\s*,\s*/, $_ } @list;
    return @list;
}
```

Output:

```
Apple
Apple:Orange
Apple:Orange:Banana
Apple:Orange:Banana:Pineapple
```